# How to decode HTML entities in Spark-scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, html-entities

I have a spark code to read some data from a database.
One of the columns (of type string) named "title" contains the following data.

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|title                                            |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|Example sentence                                 |
|Read the &#8216;Book&#8217;                      | 
|&#8216;LOTR&#8217; Is A Great Book               |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I'd like to remove the HTML entities and decode it to look as given below.

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|title                                      |
+-------------------------------------------+
|Example sentence                           |
|Read the ‘Book’                            |
|‘LOTR’ Is A Great Book                     |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

There is a library "[html-enitites](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities)" for node.js that does exactly what I am looking for,
but i am unable to find something similar for spark-scala.

What would be good approach to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils` with a help of UDF to achieve this.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

val decodeHtml =  (html:String) => {
    StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(html);
}

val decodeHtmlUDF = udf(decodeHtml)

df.withColumn("title", decodeHtmlUDF($"title")).show()

/*
+--------------------+
|               title|
+--------------------+
|   Example sentence |
|    Read the ‘Book’ |
|‘LOTR’ Is A Great...|
+--------------------+
*/
```